# Como pegar os últimos quatro meses dado determinada data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

Boa tarde pessoal! Preciso de uma função que eu informe uma data e ela me retorne a data dos quatro últimos meses, pode ser feita em angularJs ou javascript, podem me dar alguma ajuda com isso?

Quero pegar os quatro últimos meses/ano de uma data por exemplo

```
"Fri Sep 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300"
```

e o exemplo de saída

```
"Fri Sep 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300", 
"Fri Out 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300", 
"Fri Nov 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300", 
"Fri Dez 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300"
```

Comment: Ok, mas as soluções dadas não preveem esse problema e se vc passar uma data em que o dia é 31  vai receber um resultado errado. Então certifique-se de não usar nenhum dia acima de 28.  basta testar com 'Tue Oct 31 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300'   q vc vê q, apesar do mês dado ser outubro, ele retorna o mês antecessor como outubro novamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugestão `JavaScript`:

```
function foobar( dt )
{
    var array = [];

    var d = new Date( dt );

    for( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        var m = d.getMonth();

        d.setMonth( m - 1 );

        if( d.getMonth() != m - 1 && (d.getMonth() != 11 || (m == 11 && d.getDate() == 1)))
            d.setDate(0);

        array[i] = new Date(d);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Testando com `HTML`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            function foobar( dt )
            {
                var array = [];

                var d = new Date( dt );

                for( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                {
                    var m = d.getMonth();

                    d.setMonth( m - 1 );

                    if( d.getMonth() != m - 1 && (d.getMonth() != 11 || (m == 11 && d.getDate() == 1)))
                        d.setDate(0);

                    array[i] = new Date(d);
                }

                return array;
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>

            var d = foobar( 'Sep 22 2017' );

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                window.document.write( d[i] + '<BR>' );

            window.document.write( '<BR>' );

            var d = foobar( 'Apr 30 2017' );

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                window.document.write( d[i] + '<BR>' );

            window.document.write( '<BR>' );

            var d = foobar( 'Oct 31 2017' );

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                window.document.write( d[i] + '<BR>' );


        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Saída:

```
Tue Aug 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Sat Jul 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Thu Jun 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Mon May 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300

Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Tue Feb 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Sat Jan 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0200
Wed Dec 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200

Sat Sep 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Wed Aug 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Sun Jul 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
Fri Jun 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300
```

Comment: Se jogar 30 de abril neste código ele retorna 30 de março, 02 de março, 02 de Fev e 02 de Jan.

Comment: Como apenas o mês é relevante, para corrigir basta colocar: d.setDate(1);  antes do d.setMonth( d.getMonth() - 1 );

Comment: @CCastro,  huahuahua, com 31 de outubro nada retorna como desejado

Comment: @CCastro Resposta Editada

Answer (score 4):

Para gerar a data do dia nos últimos quatro meses:

```js
function mesAnterior(date, diff) {
  const d = new Date(date);
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + diff);
  return d;
}

function dataNosUltimosQuatroMeses(data) {
  const datas = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    datas.push(mesAnterior(data, i * -1));
  }
  return datas;
}

const hoje = new Date();
console.log(dataNosUltimosQuatroMeses(hoje));
```

Se quiseres nos próximos/futuros 4 meses é só mudar `i * -1` para `i * 1`

Comment: Obrigado meus caros, era isso mesmo que eu precisava!

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi você está querendo exibir a(s) data(s) exata(s) a cada X meses atrás, veja se te atende:

```js
function exibeData(){
  var dataPreenchida = document.getElementById("Data").value;
  var qtd = document.getElementById("Quantidade").value;
  if(dataPreenchida){
    while(qtd>0){
      console.log(subtraiMes(dataPreenchida, qtd));
      qtd--;
    }
  }
}

function subtraiMes(str, qtd){
    var d = new Date(str);
    d.setMonth( d.getMonth( ) - qtd );
    return d;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Preencha a data</p>
  <input type="date" name="Data" id="Data" />
</div>
<div>
  <p>Quantidade de meses atrás</p>
  <select name="Quantidade" id="Quantidade">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="exibeData();">
    Exibe data
  </button>
</div>
```